# Visual Studio 2008 Custom Controls in .NETCF 3.5 Not Showing all properties

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, custom-controls

I have a .NETCF project that I have been trying to convert from .NETCF 2.0 to .NETCF 3.5 for a while now. The solution contains about 7 projects. I had no trouble using visual stuidos conversion techniques, however, when my application ran it would randomly crash without throwing any type of exception. I have now tried to start a new project from scratch and here is where my question comes in...

One of the projects in the solution contains custom controls. One of the custom controls is a menubar that contains a collection of MenuItems. I have created a public property called Items. I have set the **Browsable** attribute set to true in the .XMTA file, and this property still does not show up in the properties window. It does show up in VS2005 under .NETCF 2.0.

Also, the control only displays a box with the class name instead of painting the control in the designer. I do have **DesktopCompatible** attribute set to true as well...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
BD

Comment: I've only created a very few user controls, and none for my compact devices. That said, I did have to add some `Invalidate` or `Refresh` commands after setting new values on my controls. Maybe that can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the preview part, it's not supported by the designer.